# JavaFx ListView, getting the text value of a cell in the list

Tags: java, listview, javafx, cucumber

I am trying to get the text of the selected cell in a ListView as it is displayed on a JavaFx application.

The purpose of this is to fix a bug I encountered when writing an application. The text of the cells in the ListView would not update properly when the underlying model changed. Which has worked in the past.
I am trying to write a cucumber acceptance test, so that if it occurs again the bug will be caught.

Below is the stepdefs for this particular scenario.

```
@Given("^I have selected an item from the list display$")
public void I_have_selected_an_item_from_the_list_display() throws Throwable {
    ListView displayList = (ListView) primaryStage.getScene().lookup("#displayList");
    displayList.getSelectionModel().select(0);
}

@When("^I edit the items short name$")
public void I_edit_the_items_short_name() throws Throwable {
    fx.clickOn("#projectTextFieldShortName").type(KeyCode.A);
    fx.clickOn("#textFieldLongName");
}

@Then("^the short name is updated in the list display$")
public void the_short_name_is_updated_in_the_list_display() throws Throwable {
    ListView displayList = (ListView) primaryStage.getScene().lookup("#displayList");
    String name = "";
    // This gets me close, In the debuger the cell property contains the cell I need, with the text
    Object test = displayList.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(0);

    //This will get the actual model object rather than the text of the cell, which is not what I want.
    Object test2 = displayList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

    assertTrue(Objects.equals("Testinga", name));
}
```

I have looked through the ListView JavaDoc and could not find any methods that can get me the text of the cell.

Comment: Somewhere you must have set the cell factory on the `ListView` to display something other than the result of calling the model's `toString()` method. Just move that functionality out into a separate method, then call it, passing the model object (which you just get with `listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()`).

Comment: Purposely I'm not using cell factories. So this won't help me unfortunately.

Comment: So what is the value displayed in the cell?

Comment: [example](https://puu.sh/hhC6r/4e9bb63601.png) I have changed the Name of Dave Fred to Not Dave and it has not updated in the listView. This is the bug I am fixing and wanting to write a test around.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If the data in your model is different to the data displayed then you have not set things up correctly (though the correct way to do this is with cell factories).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `ListView`, then either the text displayed in the cell is the result of calling `toString()` on the model object, or you have set a cell factory on the `ListView`. In the latter case, just refactor the logic to get the display text into a separate method:

```
ListView<MyModelObject> listView = ... ;

listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<MyModelObject>() {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(MyModelObject item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            setText(getDisplayText(item));
        }
    }
};

// ...

private String getDisplayText(MyModelObject object) {
    // ...
    return ... ;
}
```

Then you just need to do

```
MyModelObject item = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
String displayText = getDisplayText(item);
```

(And obviously, if you haven't set a cell factory, you just need `listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString()`)

Comment: Unfortunately the text in the cell does not update. However the model does update when editing a field.  I am also not using cell factories.
'listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem.toString()'
will call the toString method of the object that is linked to the cell. Not the text of the cell itself.

Comment: What do you mean "I am not using cell factories". How are the cells in the list view created any other way?

Comment: You can use an ObservableList, which is tied to the ListView
You would have the following in an initializer of a controller `listView.setItems(observableList);`
Then you can add items to the observableList and they will appear in the listView

Comment: In that case, assuming you don't explicitly set a cell factory, listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString() gives you the text displayed in the list view.

Comment: Because the listView has not been refreshed the text displayed is the old text. However calling `listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString()` will get the text the the listView will display if it is updated. I want to get the currently displayed text regardless if the listView has updated or not.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you are saying you are deliberately breaking the ListView by avoiding the usual mechanisms for it to update appropriately, and you want to know what the incorrect value is that is displayed in the cell. I kind of suspect this may not be a supported use case. Can you explain in a larger sense what you are trying to achieve?